# Possible to raise an exception/assertion within a logical expression

Tags: python

If I want to raise an error if `x` is empty I can do something like the following:

```
x = ...
if not x: raise SomeException(...)
```

Or:

```
assert x, "Some Exception"
```

My question is whether it's possible to do the exception/assertion as part of a logical statement or whether it's part of the python syntax that it has to be its own separate statement, by that I mean doing something like:

```
z = x**2 or raise SomeException("Value cannot be zero")
```

Or:

```
z = x**2 or assert x...
```

Or:

```
z = x**2, assert ...
```

Or whatever way to do that, I hope my intention is clear. Is it possible to do this in python?

Comment: No, `raise` and `assert` are both statements, they cannot be combined as part of expressions like that.

Comment: Python is not Ruby. Python preferes readability to *fancy syntax*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is invalid in python.
What you can do is create a function which checks a given calculation and raises an exception / asserts as follows:

```
def test_and_raise(result):
    if not result:
        raise SomeException("Some text")

    return result


z = test_and_raise(x**2)
```

If you want you can even extend it to specify the type of exception you want to throw:

```
def test_and_raise(result, exception_type):
    if not result:
        raise exception_type("Some text")

    return result


z = test_and_raise(x**2, AssertionError)
```

One caveat though, you need to be aware that the exception will be raised whenever the result is **0, None or False** so with the wrong usage you might encounter unwanted behavior

Comment: "Unfortunately this syntax is invalid in python. " I would say, *fortunately* this syntax is invalid